# How do I reduce the number of colors used in ImageDraw.text

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a folder with .ttf and .otf fonts and would like to write them on my ImageDraw object but with NO shading. A single RGB only. I have tried bitmap fonts but they A) don't look nice and B) use more than one color anyway.

I have read that there is a library for converting .bdf to .pil. If I convert arial.ttf to arial.bdf and then to arial.pil, will this be what I'm looking for? The text will almost always be dropped onto a background--so should I consider writing the text first on a blank canvas, do a color reduction, and then paste that canvas onto my background?

I have previously made this program using Java and it writes text very nicely on my bitmaps. One color, symmetrical, etc. Image below.

[image: Java font rendering]

Below are the two attempts with python. The blockier one is a bitmap font, the other is regular arial.ttf.

[image: Python Arial Bitmap]

[image: Python Arial]

Here is my code:

```
def personalize(self):

    names = self.personalize_entry.get("1.0", 'end-1c').split('\n')
    num_names = len(names)
    num_grids = math.ceil(num_names/20)
    answer = ask_grid_background()
    separator = Image.new('RGB', (473, 1), color_dict['P'])
    background = Image.new('RGB', (473, 821), color_dict['.'])

    if answer:
        showinfo("Bitmap", "Give me the design.")
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        filename = path_leaf(file_path)
        filename = filename[:-4]
        __, __, center = read(file_path)
        if center == 0:
            messagebox.showinfo("Hmmm", f"I couldn't find a center...are you sure this is a basic set up?")
            return False
        img = Image.open(file_path)
        size_num = img.size
        section = img.crop((5, (size_num[1] - 55 - center), 478, (size_num[1] - center - 15)))
        background.paste(separator, (0, 0))
        for i in range(20):
            background.paste(section, (0, (41 * i + 1)))
            background.paste(separator, (0, (41 * i) + 41))
    else:
        background.paste(separator, (0, 0))
        for i in range(20):
            # background.paste(section,(0,(41*i+1)))
            background.paste(separator, (0, (41 * i) + 41))

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(background)
    fnt = ImageFont.truetype("Fonts/PIXEAB__.ttf",36)
    draw.text((10, 10), names[0], font=fnt, fill=(0, 0, 0))
    background.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImageDraw` has an undocumented member `fontmode`, which can be set to `'1'` (cf. Pillow's image [modes](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes)) to turn off the anti-aliasing of the rendered text.

Let's compare common rendered text, `draw.fontmode` is implicitly set to `'L'`:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

image = Image.new('RGB', (800, 200), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 150)
draw.text((10, 10), 'Hello World', font=font, fill=(0, 0, 0))
image.save('image.png')
```

[image: With anti-aliasing]

Now, let's explicitly set `draw.fontmode = '1'`:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

image = Image.new('RGB', (800, 200), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.fontmode = '1'
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 150)
draw.text((10, 10), 'Hello World', font=font, fill=(0, 0, 0))
image.save('image.png')
```

[image: Without anti-aliasing]

Et voilà – no anti-aliasing, all pixels are solid black.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1
Pillow:        8.2.0
----------------------------------------
```